# How to fetch data from url containing fragment identifiers in R?

Tags: r

I tried to fetch data using  [this](http://www.squawka.com/teams/arsenal/stats#performance-score#english-barclays-premier-league#season-2015/2016#165#all-matches#1-38#by-match).

The data (performance score, total goals scored etc) for season 2015/2016 is perfectly getting fetched in R using getUrl() and readHTMLTable() method.

But, when I tried the same code using [url for 2012/2013](http://www.squawka.com/teams/arsenal/stats#performance-score#english-barclays-premier-league#season-2012/2013#2#all-matches#1-38#by-match), data of 2015/2016 is getting fetched. I identified the reason but could not solve the problem. If you visit this link, you will see that the content loaded is for season 2015/2016, then, after getting refreshed, the data for 2012/2013 is being loaded. This delay is resulting into wrongly fetching of data into R.

As the url contains fragment identifier, this delay is taking place. I found out from online source that fragments are not sent in HTTP Request Messages. The fragment identifier is only used by the browser – it doesn’t affect which resource is returned from the server.

Is there any way in R by which I can fetch data under the mentioned fragment identifier?

Answer (score 1):

As it appears that you know what your are doing with `R` (comment if you need more datail), I would check out `RSelenium` which uses your local broswer (use firefox!) to retrieve data. As a consequence you will get the post jss/ajax etc rendered HTML. There is a lot to learn!

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-basics.html